# How to print the only non-empty cell in a 1 x 50 Dataframe? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a script that generates DataFrames with 1 row and 50 columns. Each cell of each DataFrame contains a string. However, with the possible exception of one cell, all these strings contain no elements, so they look like this: `''`. As a result, each DataFrame looks something like this:

```
    Col 1        Col 2  ...  Col 49        Col 50
0                            "Here it is."
```

Only one of the cells may contain a full sentence (the one in column 49 in this case), but it is unknown what the sentence is and in which column it is located. And I want to return only that sentence. What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the sentence beforehad?

Comment: No, I do not know it beforehand.

Comment: For a dataframe with just one row, a Series seems more appropriate. Then, it should also be easier to pick out the one element with a non-empty string.

Comment: The script is part of large script that has to work with DataFrames.

Comment: First of all, I believe you should investigate *why* you end up with a data frame like this. To me, seems like the problem is in the step before this.

Comment: Wonder if `df.replace('', float('nan')).stack()` gets you close?

Comment: You can join the strings using sum and strip. s = df.sum(1).str.strip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Series instead, it is easy to filter the one cell with a non-empty element:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [""], 'col2': [""], 'col3': [""], 'col4': ["some words"], 'col5': [""]})
s = df.T[0]
sentence = s[s != ""]
```

This transposes the dataframe, then converts it to a Series. It is of course easier and quicker if you can store the data in a Series in the first place.
Or, as RafaelC hints at in a comment: avoid storing all the empty strings in the first place, and store the non-empty string directly in your variable, skipping the dataframe completely.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that empty strings are falsey

```
df.at[0, df.loc[0].astype(bool).idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.  Given this scenario

```
import pandas as pd

row = ['' for i in range(50)]
row[34] = 'Raining somewhere'
pdf = pd.DataFrame([row])
```

which looks like

```
In [5]: print(pdf)
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
0                               ...                              

[1 rows x 50 columns]
```

We can get a data frame that contains columns with entries that are not `''` with

```
pdf[pdf !=''].dropna(axis = 1)
```

which returns

```
                  34
0  Raining somewhere
```

If you just want the string

```
pdf[pdf !=''].dropna(axis = 1).values[0][0]
```

returns

```
'Raining somewhere'
```

This assumes that there is only one such string in the data frame.  Alternately if you didn't want to use `pdf != ''` you could always use

```
import numpy as np
pdf.replace('',np.nan).dropna(axis = 1).values[0][0]
```